# Alert Dialog for a drawable

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-menu

I already have an `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` for a *submit* button.

In the

```
switch(item.getItemId()){
case R.id.submit:
```

I want an alertDialog. How may I do that. This *submit* is the id for the image in the res>drawable folder.
So how can I add an alert dialog to this?

Summarizing: I want a confirmation for the submit button clicked. Upon a *yes* I want to call the `submitDefects();` function.

Comment: **submit** is not the resource id of the image, but of the menu item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item)
 {
 switch(item.getItemId()){
 case R.id.submit:
  AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("TITLE");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want delete this?");

    // Setting Icon to Dialog
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);

    // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

        // Write your code here to invoke YES event
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     submitDefects();
        }
    });

    // Setting Negative "NO" Button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // Write your code here to invoke NO event
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You clicked on NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
            return true;
        }
    }
```